How to disable the left-sided application switcher on Mac that shows when mouse is moved to the left side?

I updated my Mac. One day, it suggested I switch to a new page switcher mode. I was eager to test it. After a while, I decided to move the setting back. Unfortunately, I couldn't find out how to return to the previous settings.

The feature is called "Stage Manager". You can turn it off in System Settings:
Choose Apple menu > System Settings, then click Desktop & Dock  in the sidebar. (You may need to scroll down.) Go to Desktop & Stage Manager, then turn Stage Manager on or off.
